# Get user posts from LinkedIn API

Tags: javascript, postman, linkedin-api

After a long search I was not able to use the LinkedIn API to retrieve a user's posts. My goal is to connect a user with a "connect with LinkedIn" button and retrieve all of that user's LinkedIn posts.

Is it possible ?

I can't understand the documentation, there are lots of mixed versions...

For now I can only recover `/userinfo`.